# Programmatically auto-submit a Webform after visiting its URL

Tags: 8, forms, webforms, uri

I am wondering whether it's possible to programmatically auto-submit a Webform after visiting its URL and to save the user from a 'submit' button click.

The below webform can be accessed via `/form/my-invoices`:

[image: My Webform]

and has 3 elements:

- Key: invoice_number
- Key: amount
- Key: seller_name

**Use Case:**

I have paper invoice with a printed barcode and a barcode reader device.

When a user will scan the barcode on the paper invoice, The barcode result will be generated and the user will be redirected to:

```
www.example.com/form/my-invoices?invoice_number=123456789&amount=1200&seller_name:john-smith
```

I want to **auto-submit the Webform** when the above link will be visited !

**So in steps, below what will really happen:**

1. A user will scan the barcode.
2. Barcode will then redirect the user to
   `www.example.com/form/my-invoices?invoice_number=123456789&amount=1200&seller_name:john-smith`
3. **AUTOMATICALLY, the elements of the webform (form/my-invoices) will be populated from the link query parameter and the webform will be
   auto-submitted without having the user to click on the "Submit"
   button.**
4. After auto submit of the webform, the user will be redirected to:
   `/specific-url` and with a confirmation message something similar
   to: "the webform has been auto-submitted on your behalf".

So in summary, how to programmatically auto-submit a webform when the webform url with query parameters is visited ?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE #2 (edit #2):**

After changing the route path to: `/form/my-invoices/autosubmit` and visit that page, the webform is indeed successfully submitted by **there is no value validation occured**:

**autosubmit_barcode_results.routing.yml**

```
autosubmit_barcode_results.autosubmitform:
  path: '/form/my-invoices/autosubmit'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\autosubmit_barcode_results\Controller\AutoSubmitBarcodeController::autosubmitform'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**AutoSubmitBarcodeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\autosubmit_barcode_results\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AutoSubmitBarcodeController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function autosubmitform() {

// Get and prepare variables.
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$invoive_number = $request->query->get('invoive_number'); 

// Get submission values and data.
$values = [
  'webform_id' => 'my_invoices',
  'entity_type' => NULL,
  'entity_id' => NULL,
  'in_draft' => FALSE,
  'uid' => '1',
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'token' => 'pgmJREX2l4geg2RGFp0p78Qdfm1ksLxe6IlZ-mN9GZI',
  'uri' => '/webform/my_invoices/api',
  'remote_addr' => '',
  'data' => [
    'invoice_number' => $invoice_number,
  ],
];

// Validate submission.
  $errors = WebformSubmissionForm::validateFormValues($values);

// Check there are no validation errors.
  if (!empty($errors)) {
     $message = $errors['invoice_number'];
     $message = drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
     return $message;
  }
  else {
// If no validation errors, then Submit values and get submission ID.
    $webform_submission = WebformSubmissionForm::submitFormValues($values);


// Redirect the user.
return new RedirectResponse('/all-my-scanned-invoices');

// Show a success message to the user on the redirected page.
 $mesagesuccess = 'New invoice has been successfully scanned.';
 $mesagesuccess = drupal_set_message($mesagesuccess, 'status');
 return $mesagesuccess;

    }
  }
}
```

**However when an invoice is scanned twice,** the `$error` is being displayed properly but along with another error:

```
You have already scanned this invoice once, please scan another one!

User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).
Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children(Array, 1) (Line: 408)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it basically in 3 steps:

1.Get and prepare your variables:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$invoice_number = $request->query->get('invoice_number');
$amount = ...;
$seller_name = ...;
```

2.[Create a submission](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-create-and-update-a-submission) when `/form/my-invoices` is requested and all of three variables are present/valid. (meet whatever conditions applicable to your case). This step can be done in various ways, such as a controller/service, or a preprocess hook...Well, step 1 and 3 are actually all part of this function.

The preprocess function (mymodule_preprocess _page(&$var)) can go into the `my_module/my_module.module` file, while a controller can go into `my_module/src/Controller/FormSubmitController.php` file.
Preprocess function does check all incoming requests, but as long as you `return` early, it's not too bad IMO... However the Drupal8 OOP elegant way is to provide a route and trigger the controller when route is active. You can look up [some tutorials on that topic](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example). For validating your webform, search for [webform validation tutorials](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21MessengerInterface.php/interface/MessengerInterface/8.5.x).

3.Upon successful creation, use

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
return new RedirectResponse('http://yoursite.com/specific-url');
```

Do a security check on the variables before the submission creation if necessary and you should be all set.

**Update about validation question:**

First of all, if your barcode is capable of generating unique invoice numbers, and as long as you make sure it doesn't get altered before the submit function is triggered, we don't necessarily have to validate it.
In this specific case, I believe all you need to do is going into the webform build page, and check the `unique` box for the invoice_number field. The great Webform module already has it built in so if there's an duplicate, it will not submit, and you will have something in the `$error` variable. You can get the error message and display it however you want.

Check this page for [all the methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21MessengerInterface.php/interface/MessengerInterface/8.5.x) you can use on \Drupal::messenger()

```
// Validate submission.
  $errors = WebformSubmissionForm::validateFormValues($values);

// Check there are no validation errors.
  if (!empty($errors)) { 
    //$message = $errors['invoice_number'];
    // \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll(); use this if you don't want to show the field level error message. It delete all messages.
    \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('An error occurred and processing did not complete'));
    $render = [
        '#type' => 'StatusMessages', // use this render array type to display messages. 
    ];
    return $render;
  }
  else {
// If no validation errors, then Submit values and get submission ID.
    $webform_submission = WebformSubmissionForm::submitFormValues($values);
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('New invoice has been successfully scanned.'));
    return new RedirectResponse('/all-my-scanned-invoices');
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much but I am in the process of learning drupal php and file structure so still a bit confused here! **(1)** In what file of my custom module I have to include all the above code ? **(2)** What is the best function to be used to trigger the above code ? (thinking to check the path everytime will change and compare it if equal to the webform path so only then trigger the code but not sure is good idea in term of performance). **(3)** The validation of the elements before submit is very very important becasue the **ticket_number** is **unique** and cannot be used twice.Thanks

Comment: excuse my ignorance but still a bit confused here! Can you please check the UPDATE #2 of the question

Comment: I would follow along that routing/controller tutorial link I sent and start from there. If you are not ready for OOP yet, use the preprocess function in the mymodule.module file.

Comment: I have already setup my custom module along with both route & controller files and yet still nothing is happening when I visit the `/form/my-invoices` link... Please be kind and check the code in the edit section of my question

Comment: I see, I think you are very close here. So it looks like the webform route is taking precedence over your custom route (`/form/my-invoices`). For testing purpose, change your custom route to `/form/my-invoices/submit`, go to that page, and see if the webform creation works. I also notice the `autosubmitform` function does not return anything, you can actually put step3 code here as the return statement.

Comment: For testing purposes, I have changed the function code to `drupal_set_message('success');` and I have also changed the route path to become `/form/my-invoices/submit` and when I visit the `../submit` path, an error occured on a white dead screen but when I click the browser back button, the message "Success" is now displayed. Please see **UPDATE #3** for the error description.

Comment: Yeah the error is complaining about there's no return statement in your controller. Once you set a proper `return` the error should be fixed. Please see last part of my previous comment.

Comment: You are right, the `return` was the issue here and now the webform is being programmatically submitted. However, the validation of the values are not working as it should. For Ex, the **invoice_number** is unique and cannot be submitted twice, when I try to programmatically submit the **invoice_number** twice, simply the submission is not created but **there is no validation error displayed for the user** such as: `The invoice_number is unique and cannot be submitted twice`

Comment: I added the validation section at the bottom of my answer, also you have a typo `invoice` in the code haha

Comment: thank you for the typo note! For the validation, I am already using the `unique` checkbox with the unique message: `You have already scanned this invoice before, please scan another invoice`. However, when I scan the same invoice twice, the `$error` variable is not printed to the user. **When same invoice is scanned twice**, no new submission is created which is good but the `$error` variable is not printed... Thank you

Comment: They need to be returned respectively within the if/else. Please see my updated code, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your continuous help, I will mark your answer accepted and you have really taught me so much about custom module and controllers. Please if you can add to your answer two more things: **(1)** how to display the message within a red rectangle like Drupal do with the "Green", "Red" or "Orange" messages. **(2)** After redirecting to new page, I used `\Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('New Invoice added.');` to display a green color message to the user but it is not working and no message is displayed. **I have added this code after the** `return`, Thank you!

Comment: Hope this will be my last comment, please see my update on the question... there is a new error available.

Comment: Also when redirecting the user, the `$messagesuccess` is not displayed... the `$messagesuccess` is displayed only when there is no redirection page in the code. So as i understand, one `return` only is being used... I am not able to use **two** return in one request

Comment: Happy to help, I have updated the code at the bottom.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough for your continuous support ! @cchen you are code saver !

Comment: Great! You're welcome!